# Stop Visual Studio 2019 from constantly evaluating ToString()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

To reproduce my issue:

1. Paste the following code into a new C# .NET Framework console application in Visual Studio 2019.
2. Put a breakpoint on the line `_Bar = null`
3. Start debugging
4. At the breakpoint, hover over `_Bar` to view its value
5. Step over
6. Step over
7. The exception is thrown

It looks like Visual Studio is continuously evaluating the `ToString()` method, causing `_Bar` to always have the value `FooBar` despite setting it to `null`. Is there a way to stop it? The issue is **not** reproducible in Visual Studio 2013. I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.0.1.

```cs
    using System;

    namespace FooBar {
        class Program {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                new Foo();
            }

            class Foo {
                string _Bar;
                public string Bar {
                    get {
                        if (_Bar == null) {
                            _Bar = "FooBar";
                        }
                        return _Bar;
                    }
                    set {
                        _Bar = value;
                    }
                }

                public Foo() {
                    _Bar = null;
                    if (_Bar != null) {
                        throw new Exception("_Bar is not null.");
                    }
                }

                public override string ToString() {
                    return Bar;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: every time you get _Bar you set it to foobar if it's null.

Comment: @Scriven Tha's true for `Bar`, but not `_Bar`

Comment: "It looks like Visual Studio is continuously evaluating the ToString() method" - are you sure it's not just evaluating the Bar property in the Watch Window? Fundamentally this is the problem with including side-effects in property getters...

Comment: VS considers property getters having no side-effects, hence evaluates them. And it doesn't do that for methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, I didn't have the watch window automatically displayed in the previous version of Visual Studio. Removing the object from the watch list in VS2019 did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution to the problem is to disable property evaluation in the general debugging options

[image]

Edit: Another solution to the problem if you don't have a Watch window with the property on it.